# Comparison with stl sort()

Tags: c++, sorting, syntax, stl

I'm trying to use stl sort() in a class function.  I would like to sort an array of structs that look like this:

```
struct foo{
    double num;
    std::string s;
};
```

with a comparison function like this:

```
bool aGreaterThanb(foo a, foo b){
    if (a.num > b.num){
        if(a.num == b.num){
            if (anotherOutsideComparison(a.s, b.s)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

But I'm not sure how I can format this to get it to compile.  How should I format this so I can call `sort(fooarray[0], fooarray[end], aGreaterThanb);`? (An example would be great)

Comment: It should work as is. You just have a syntax error in your code (You are missing a close brace '}' after the return true). To me this is a good reason to line up the open and close braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works just as you want already:

```
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    foo     data[10];
    std::sort(&data[0], &data[10], aGreaterThanb);
}
```

But you have syntax error. You are missing a brace:

```
        return true;
} // <--- Missing this line
else
    return false;
```

For efficiency you should pass by const reference:

```
bool aGreaterThanb(foo const& a, foo const& b){
```

Comment: the last index of the declaration `foo data[10]` is 9, so, your statement should be `std::sort(&data[0], &data[9], aGreaterThanb);`

Comment: @Sergio Moura: No. The std algorithms require the `end point` of a range to be one past the end of the range. Just like begin() will give you the first element and end() will give you one past the end &data[10] is one past the end. This is explicitly allowed by the standard and required when you use the standard algorithms on a normal array.

Comment: Actually OP is missing a semicolon after `true` as well.

Answer (score 4):

Write your comparison function as the `operator()` method of a structure called a *functor*:

```
struct aGreaterThanb
{
    bool operator() (const foo& a, const foo& b)
    {
        // return true iff a is strictly less than b according to your ordering
    }
};
```

Then pass an instance of that functor object to `std::sort`:

```
std::sort(fooarray.begin(), fooarray.end(), aGreaterThanb());
```

Comment: hidden point: pass by reference to avoid copying the arguments on each invocation

Comment: Functions work fine in std::sort(). Personally I would prefer to a use a functor (like you) but the code above can be used without change (when the syntax error is fixed). See below.

Comment: This answer seems like overkill since he doesn't need state.  All he has to do it change to pass-by-reference.

Comment: The question doesn't mention anything about STL-containers, so .begin() .end() would not work.

Comment: I'm using an array of these stucts, how would I format the beginning element and the end element? sort(array[0], array[end], compart()) doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using an array of `foo` like this:

```
foo fooarray[Foos];
...
sort(fooarray, fooarray + Foos, &aGreaterThanb);
```

The above code would sort your array in reverse order, since sort expects a less-than comparator.

Additionally to avoid copying a lot of `foo`-objects around just for comparison, declare your comparator to take `const foo&` instead of `foo` as arguments.

```
bool aGreaterThanb(const foo& a, const foo& b) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You're supposed to pass iterators — a generalized superset of pointers — to the STL `sort` function:

```
std::sort(fooarray, fooarray + end, &aGreaterThanb);
```

Comment: Doesn't `std::sort` expect a less-than function anyway, not a greater-than function? I think that will be a problem...

Comment: @PlatinumAzure: It will just sort the array in descending order. Probably this is OP's intention.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure: As long as the function/functor provides a `strict weak` ordering between elemenets it should work correctly.

Comment: Well, I'm just saying it might surprise the user if s/he provides a greater-than function and `sort` expects a less-than function. As KennyTM points out, it will result in a descending sort. Ascending sort is by far the more common preference.

Answer (score 0):

Make it an operator.

```
struct foo {
    double num;
    std::string s;
};

bool operator>(const foo& a, const foo& b) {
    return (
        (a.num > b.num) ||
        ((a.num == b.num) &&
        anotherOutsideComparison(a.s, b.s))
    );
}

// note: std::sort expects operator<
bool operator<(const foo& a, const foo& b) {
    return b > a;
}
```

If you really want to sort using operator>, pass `std::greater<foo>()` as the functor.

```
std::sort(foos.begin(), foos.end(), std::greater<foo>());
```

Comment: `!(a > b)` means `a <= b`. Perhaps you mean `b > a`.

Comment: I think your first `&&` should be `||`

Answer (score 0):

Note that in worst case sort function is up to N^2 comparsions.
And stable_sort complexity is between N*logN and N*(LogN^2)